# Keeping a child div from expanding a flexbox div

Tags: css, flexbox

Well, here on this fiddle I have two divs aligned with `display:flex` and `flex-grow`: https://jsfiddle.net/h7bm23ts/2/

```js
window.longer = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("child2")[0].innerHTML += "like this and ";
};
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: beige;
  height: 300px;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 300px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">
  some nonsense
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
  longer nonsense <button onclick="window.longer();"> even longer </button>
  <div class="child1">
    this child should be able to expand this div
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    this child should wrap when too much content is appended
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the content in one of the divs is dynamic and when more content is appended onto a child div of it, the parent div expands and makes the boxes wrap, ruining the layout with a few button clicks.

How do I keep the gray div from expanding on more content and make it simply accept its parent's width as "strict" and wrap in it?

**EDIT**: I settled on https://jsfiddle.net/h7bm23ts/12/.

Comment: What about removing `flex-wrap: wrap` from the container? https://jsfiddle.net/h7bm23ts/5/

Comment: it's not entirely clear what it is you are trying to do. If the beige div is not allowed  to shrink it must have a defined size. `flex-grow:2` isn't enough. Something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/6bzbg2tq/2/

Comment: @Michael_B: The cyan div still pushes the beige div to the left, and after a point the content in the beige div will be illegible. People actually suggested this twice.

Comment: @Paulie_D: If I am going to give a fixed size to the beige div, what is the point of using flexbox? What I want is, the gray div should accept its parent's width as something like "screen size" and don't ever try to grow it bigger.

Comment: Well you can't do that....flexbox can't solve **every** problem. You want a min-width on the beige div so you'll have to set it somehow.

Comment: But with `flex-grow: 2` on the parent div, the width can vary. The child has no width limit. That's why a fixed width is useful here. https://jsfiddle.net/h7bm23ts/9/

Comment: @sikerbela Have you tried adding `flex: 1 1 500px;` to `.box2`? https://jsfiddle.net/h7bm23ts/10/

Comment: Well, perhaps I am doing the "use all the available space with this ratio" part wrong. Is there any way else to it other than `flex-grow`?

Comment: You can use the available space but you have to let it shrink if the green block is supposed to expand the cyan block. If you do that you have to have min-width on the beige block or it will shrink until it reaches the width of it's content. - Like this - https://jsfiddle.net/6bzbg2tq/5/

Comment: That started to make sense, instead of flex-grow I can specify a min-width of, say, 50% to the beige div and flex-grow:1 to the cyan, then more content to the gray box should... oh I'll just try

Comment: It should expand to fill the space, not to eat the beige div. The `min-width` is actually helpful in this. However, more content to the gray box will still make the cyan parent uncomfortable and make it wrap downwards. The gray div should not have this ... luxury.

Comment: That's why we remove the flex-wrap - https://jsfiddle.net/6bzbg2tq/6/

Comment: and now the green div is unable to make its parent wrap downwards too, making the layout weird in narrow screens https://jsfiddle.net/6bzbg2tq/8/

Comment: Giving a `flex-basis: 60% min-width: 300px` to the beige `.box1` and `flex-basis: 40%` to the cyan `.box2` gives me something to settle on. Now they take the intended ratio on screen regardless of their content, and when the screen is too small to accommodate the min-width, the boxes wrap. Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try this css to achive what you need:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.box1 {
   background-color: beige;
   min-height: 300px;
   flex: 2 1 0; /* 2 - flex grow, 1 - flex shrink, 0 - flex basis */                       

 }

.box2 {
   background-color: cyan;
   min-height: 300px;
   flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

More about this You can find here:
https://css-tricks.com/flex-grow-is-weird/  and here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#flex-grow-property, and 
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#flexibility

Comment: Upvoted answer. It helped me quite a lot, however it is not an exact solution to my question since I wanted only the green child of `.box2` be able to grow it and not the gray.